# I need a way to assign and retrieve values between windows form (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, global

So, I'm doing a school project atm. The application needs to be able to calculate the area of squares, circles etc.

I have one form for each figure to calculate the area off. Right now I have a "main menu" and three forms (one for each figure) and I want to be able to assign a variable `LatestResult` within one form and access it from the main menu form.

Note: I want to be able to do this without "loading the variable into the new form" like this: `Form1 FormMainMenu = new Form1(LatestResult)`

I've been trying to work with Get & Set in my `Variables.cs` class, but I can't seem to make it work right, if it's possible to do it with this.

EDIT: Put my code in the post

My `Variables.cs`looks like this:

```
public static string latestresult2
{
    get
    {
        return latestresult2;
    }

     set
     {
          latestresult2 = value;
     }
 }
```

And then I assign the value upon a button click in one form:

```
Variables.latestresult2 = breddeR + " * " + længdeR + " = " + resultat;
```

breddeR and længdeR are the int variables for my calculation and resultat is the result.

At last I try to do this in another form:

```
label1.Text = Variables.latestresult2;
```

EDIT 2:

From my `MainView` form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 FormTrekant = new Form2();
    FormTrekant.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to facilitate this. This interface works with both WinForms and WPF.

```
public class Form2 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string latestresult2;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string LatestResult2
    {
        get
        {
            return latestresult2;
        }

        set
        {
            latestresult2 = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("LatestResult2");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}

public class Form3 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string latestResult3;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string LatestResult3
    {
        get
        {
            return latestresult3;
        }

        set
        {
            latestresult3 = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("LatestResult3");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface allows you to subscribe to another objects property changes. In the above code, the second form will raise the event when ever its `LatestResult2` property has had its value changed.

Now you just have your Form1 subscribe to it.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private Form2 secondaryForm;
    private Form3 thirdForm;

    public string LatestValue {get; set;}

    public void Form2ButtonClick() // Assume this happens in a button click event on MainWindow.
    {
        this.secondaryForm = new Form2();
        this.secondaryForm.PropertyChanged += this.LatestValueChanged;
        this.secondaryForm.Closing += this.ChildWindowClosing;
    }

    public void Form3ButtonClick() // Assume this happens in a button click event on MainWindow.
    {
        this.thirdForm = new Form3();
        this.thirdForm.PropertyChanged += this.LatestValueChanged;
        this.thirdForm.Closing += this.ChildWindowClosing;
    }

    private void LatestValueChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your update here.
        if (sender == this.secondaryForm)
        {
            this.LatestValue = this.secondaryForm.LatestValue2;
        }
        else if (sender == this.thirdForm)
        {
            this.LatestValue = this.thirdForm.LatestValue3;
        }
    }

    // Clean up our event handlers when either of the children forms close.
    private void ChildWindowClosing(object sender, ClosingWindowEventHandlerArgs args)
    {
        if (sender == this.secondaryForm)
        {
            this.secondaryForm.Closing -= this.ChildWindowClosing;
            this.secondaryForm.PropertyChanged -= this.LatestValueChanged;
        }
        else if (sender == this.thirdForm)
        {
            this.thirdForm.Closing -= this.ChildWindowClosing;
            this.thirdForm.PropertyChanged -= this.LatestValueChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `MainWindow` can now react to changes within `Form2`, without having to pass values around. One thing to note, is that you will want to unsubscribe from the event when the `Form2` is closed. Otherwise you will leak.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long response! I'm thinking a lot of your first suggestion. The "problem" is just I need this to work with a total of 3 forms.

Should I do the `INotifyProperyChanged` on all of the three forms then or wouldn't it really work out since I have more than one?

Comment: As long as all 3 forms implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your `MainView` can subscribe to all 3. I will update the answer to show you subscribing to two forms, and unsubscribing when those forms are closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I'll try it out soon and hopefully make it work.

Comment: Just to clarify as I'm a bit unsure. What is `propertyName` supposed to be?

Comment: `propertyName` is the property that changed. When a property changes, you pass that property name in to the `OnPropertyChanged` method. Objects that subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event can then look at the arguments provided and evaluate what property changed if they need to.

Comment: I get an error on this part:
`private virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }`

"Form2.OnPropertyChanged(string)': virtual or abstract members cannot be private"

Comment: Sorry, you can remove the `virtual` keyword and it'll be fine. I updated my answer to show that. The virtual piece was left over from the original source I copied it out of, I forgot to remove it when I was tweaking the code for this post.

Comment: I still have some errors in the Get&Set on the Form2

`public static string LatestResult2
        {
            get
            {
                return latestresult2;
            }

            set
            {
                latestresult2 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("LatestResult2");
            }
        }`

**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'namespace.Form2.latestresult2'** (for both get and set)

and

**Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer**

Comment: Yeah, those properties can't be static. You have to make them just normal properties as shown in my example.

Comment: Okay, so I'm working on it but haven't gotten it to work just yet. I'm gonna go to bed now and finish it tomorrow. I hope I can ask you here again if I need further help. If not thanks for all up untill now!

Comment: Since you are new, I'll remind you to make sure and select someones answer here if any of them end up being the thing that works best for you.

Comment: I'll remember that! But, can you please explain me what Childwindow would be here: `this.secondaryForm.Closing += this.ChildWindowClosing;` and how should I write it as my code currently looks like this: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.secondaryForm = new Form2();
            this.secondaryForm.PropertyChanged += this.LatestValueChanged;


            secondaryForm.Show();
        }`

Comment: Everything you need is in my answer. `ChildWindow` is just a method inside MainView that is called when `secondaryForm` is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the instance of the main view to the other view. This way, you can access the properties of the main view.

Some code to explaain;

```
public class MainView
{
    public string LatestResult { get; set; }
}

public class ChildView
{
    private readonly MainView MainView;
    public ChildView(MainView mainView)
    {
        this.MainView = mainView;
    }
    public void Calculation()
    {
        //Some calculation
        this.MainView.LatestResult = "Some result";
    }
}
```

Now this code can be used like this:

```
var mainView = new MainView();

var childView = new ChildView(mainView);
childView.Calculation();

//mainView.LatestResult == "Some result"
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of a child view being able to manipulate a parent view. Instead, I think an implementation of property changed events makes sense for him. Let the child view raise an event that the parent can subscribe to.

Comment: @Johnathon Sullinger: Well, the child window can access only what the main window provides, if the encapsulation is well thought, I don't see problem. Furthermore, the application (as it is defined by the OP) won't evolve too much so overthinking the application is, for me, loosing resource.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` adds less than 10 lines of code across both the parent and child view, so it's not excessive nor over thinking. It's applying the right tool for the job. If I had mentioned Pub/sub in my comment to you, then I would 100% agree on the over thinking part